# Mark Max Value dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a Array with a Statistic Object for each Player. I display the Value for each Player in a list like that:

```
<tr>
    <td *ngFor="let stat of stats">
        <div > {{stat.gameCount}}</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td *ngFor="let stat of stats">
        <div > {{stat.winCount}}</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now the Problem is, that I want to highlight the best Player for each Statistic. SO in the first row I want to give the Div with the Maximum Games Count in it another class. In the second row the same with the Maximum Win Count.

I know already, how I can dynamically apply a class to the td, but not how I can check if its the max value.

I thought I could achieve it with giving the first td e.g. this attribute, but ***TypeScript*** gives me just an useless error message:

```
[[class.stat_lbl_value_best]]="Math.max(stats.map(function(value){return value.gameCount})==stat.gameCount";
```

***The TypeScript Error is:***

> ng: TypeError: Cannot read property toUpperCase of undefined.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is almost correct, but you need to move the code in the typescript class instead of the template.
So, for example, you can create a new property that will keep the maximum value:

```
maxWins = Math.max(...this.stats.map(s => s.winCount));
```

For conditionally adding a class to an element one can use the [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive:

```
<td *ngFor="let stat of stats"
    [ngClass]="{'stat_lbl_value_best': stat.winCount === maxWins}">
```

You can achieve the functionality for the games count in a similar way.

Comment: Okay, I thought there would be also a way to do that in the Template File.. But Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `[class.stat_lbl_value_best]="stat.winCount === maxWins"`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes it does, in this case the effect is identical to using ngClass. I generally prefer ngClass since I find it easier to read/understand.